# PHP - chdir() save the new directory

Tags: php, chdir

I'm working with chdir() and it's my first time and I'm having problems when I change the directory.

Well, when I change the directory I use chdir(directory_name); but then when I check for the current directory or if I try to access to another directory that exists in the directory that I enter the first time I have an error because the actual directory didn't change

EDIT: Sorry for not show any code but I found the solution. I create a $_SESSION to store the current directory and the new directory when I change it.

```
  if(!isset($_SESSION['dir'])) {
      chdir("../../filesystem");
      $_SESSION['dir'] = getcwd();
  } else {
      chdir($_SESSION['dir']);
  }
```

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your PHP script, or check the server error log; the `chdir` call is probably failing, and PHP's error handling sucks so badly that in its default configuration it won't bother telling you about it unless you go out of your way to specify that you want to be notified.

Comment: If you are using chdir in an attempt to fix issues with relative path includes you are probably just making things worse. You are going to break everything that is currently resolving correctly.

Comment: do you use `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes, I use session_start() at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 2):

Did you check for success/failure? e.g:

```
$result = chdir('newdir');
if ($result === false) {
   die("Could not chdir()");
}
```